# How to programmatically detect and respond to a key word(s) in chat messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot

My problem is that I am fairly new to coding and I'm not exactly sure how to do this. I only know the basics of making a bot that responds to commands starting with ! but I'd like to know how to make a bot that can detect any word and respond.

For example: I have a chatango chat bot using the ch.py library and under the onMessage class I have

```
    try:
        cmd, args = message.body.split(" ", 1)
    except:
        cmd, args = message.body, ""

    if cmd[0] == "!":
        prfx = True
        cmd = cmd[1:]
    else:
        prfx = False

    if cmd.lower() == "test" and prfx:
        room.message("This is a test code.")
```

But I want to also have the bot room.message based on specific key phrases found in posted messages as well.

Sorry for my lack of experience, I just couldn't find any decent information on what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple.

```
s = "It's not safe to go alone. Take this."
if 'safe' in s:
    print('The message is safe.')
```

Or

```
if s.find('safe') != -1:
    print('This message is safe.')
```

Using `in` is faster. Using `find` works too, but the really purpose of `find` is to return index of found string.

Comment: The first one worked perfectly for what I had in mind, but I can't seem to figure how to stop it once it starts. It just spams until the chat client forces it to stop. How do I stop the code? (sorry for the newbie question.)

Comment: Ah, I managed to resolve the issue by changing the code a little bit, I was doing something dumb but I fixed it! Thanks for your help.